# JQUERY-UI: Datepicker - Disable day click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I currently have a datepicker with month and year change set to true... but as part of my user-experience report feedbacks, they didn't like the datepicker automatically closing when they select the day because sometimes they change the date in random order of selection from month, day, and year. So if for instance, they changed the date selecting Month first, then Day, the datepicker automatically closes already with the Year left unchanged.

So I was looking for something like a datepicker with the day changer just setting values and not triggering a close event and just delegating that close event to the Done button alone when showButtonPanel is set to true.

Any ideas how I would achieve that?

Here is my code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
  showButtonPanel: true,
  yearRange: 'c-70:c+nn'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this (I assume you are using jqueryui datepicker):

```
$(function() {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
           onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { inst.show() }
        });
    });
```

Comment: this results to `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'show'` inside chrome console. And day is not shown as selected. What's the problem with this?

Answer (score 3):

I would not use this solution because it is creating errors in almost every browser.:

```
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
       onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { inst.show() }
    });
});
```

The best thing you can do is to overwrite the '_selectDate' method of jQuery ui datepicker.

You do this by adding this function again to the datepicker like this:

```
$('#dateField').datepicker({

    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,

},

$.datepicker._selectDate = function(id, dateStr){
    var onSelect,
    target = $(id),
    inst = this._getInst(target[0]);

    dateStr = (dateStr != null ? dateStr : this._formatDate(inst));
    if (inst.input) {
       inst.input.val(dateStr);
    }
    this._updateAlternate(inst);

    onSelect = this._get(inst, "onSelect");
    if (onSelect) {
        onSelect.apply((inst.input ? inst.input[0] : null), [dateStr, inst]);  // trigger custom callback
    } else if (inst.input) {
        inst.input.trigger("change"); // fire the change event
    }

    if (inst.inline){
        this._updateDatepicker(inst);
    } else {

        this._lastInput = inst.input[0];
            if (typeof(inst.input[0]) !== "object") {
            inst.input.focus(); // restore focus
        }
        this._lastInput = null;
    }

})

);
```

normally there would be a 'this._hideDatepicker();' in this script. 
I left it out. You can also change the jQuery file itself, however I am not a fan of doing those things, because you will lose your functionality after updating jQuery.

With my solution there would be no need to do so.

Comment: How could you use this and have datepicker still apply the 'ui-state-active' class to the currently selected day?

Answer (score 1):

When creating the datepicker use this options:

```
$('input').datepicker({
   onClose: function(d,i){setTimeout(function(){$('input').datepicker("show");},1)}
});
```

But of course you would have to handle the real closing yourself.

```
var realClose = false;
$('input').datepicker({
   onClose: function(d,i){if(realClose)setTimeout(function(){$('input').datepicker("show"); realClose = false},1)}
});
$("#done").click(function(){realClose=true;$('input').datepicker("hide")})
```

Comment: Wouldn't this mean the datepicker could never close? It would always show again, whether the user wants to close it or not.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same solution. I wanted a OK and Cancel button and when a date is selected, that the input field is not updated unless you click on OK.

You need to adjust the following:

- add stayOpen: true to the this._defaults = { global defaults.
- in _selectDate: function(id, dateStr) { you need to adjust:

  ```
  if (inst.input)
      inst.input.val(dateStr);
  ```

to

```
    var stayOpen = this._get(inst, 'stayOpen');
    if (!stayOpen && inst.input)
        inst.input.val(dateStr);
```

because this updates the value of the input field when you select a date. You need to set stayOpen: true if you want to only change the date if you click ok, otherwise the datepicker will close when you select a new date. So that is why we also get the stayOpen so that if this is true, it will update the input field before closing.

You can also use this parameter in the else to not hide the datepicker:

```
else if (!stayOpen) {
    this._hideDatepicker();
```

- I use the close button as OK button so in _generateHTML: function(inst) { you need to adjust the data-handler="hide" of that button to something else like data-handler="ok".
- In _attachHandlers: function(inst) { you can then add a new handler to the end:

  ```
  ,
  ok: function () {
      window['DP_jQuery_' + dpuuid].datepicker._updateInput(id, inst);
  }
  ```
- you can then add a new function like this to update the input field and hide the datepicker:

  ```
  _updateInput: function(id, inst) {
      if (inst.input) {
          inst.input.val(this._formatDate(inst));
      }
      this._hideDatepicker(); 
  },
  ```