# How can I display a jquery calendar with highlight days and prohibit clicking (read only)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I use the Jquery calendar to display a daily room capacity. So far it works fine.

Now I just want to show this calendar on my start screen (read only mode). The day should not be marked, because there is no function and the user is maybe confused if the day is marked (blue) but nothing happens.

I've tried them all [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754783/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-day-click-event), but either nothing happens or the calendar is displayed without my highlights.

How can I display my highlights days and prohibit clicking?

```js
$(function() {
  var dates = [{
      date: '05/13/2020',
      type: 'highlightFull',
      note: 'note1'
    },
    {
      date: '05/11/2020',
      type: 'highlightSemi',
      note: 'note2'
    }
  ];

function highlightDays(date) {
  var res = [true, ""];
  
  $.each(dates, function(k, v) {
    if (v.date === $.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", date)) {
      res = [true, v.type, v.note];
    }
  });
  
  return res;
}

  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: highlightDays,
    onClose: function(d,i){setTimeout(function(){$('input').datepicker("show");},1)}
  });

});
```

```css
td.highlightFull {
  border: none !important;
  padding: 1px 0 1px 1px !important;
  background: none !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}

td.highlightFull a {
  background: #ad3f29 url(bg.png) 50% 50% repeat-x !important;
  border: 1px #88a276 solid !important;
}

td.highlightSemi {
  border: none !important;
  padding: 1px 0 1px 1px !important;
  background: none !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}

td.highlightSemi a {
  background: #ffff33 url(bg.png) 50% 50% repeat-x !important;
  border: 1px #88a276 solid !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have some CSS - remove the tbody if you do not even want them to change month

```
#datepicker tbody [data-event=click] { pointer-events: none; }
```

```js
$(function() {
  var dates = [{
      date: '05/13/2020',
      type: 'highlightFull',
      note: 'note1'
    },
    {
      date: '05/11/2020',
      type: 'highlightSemi',
      note: 'note2'
    }
  ];

function highlightDays(date) {
  var res = [true, ""];
  
  $.each(dates, function(k, v) {
    if (v.date === $.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", date)) {
      res = [true, v.type, v.note];
    }
  });
  
  return res;
}

  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: highlightDays,
    onClose: function(d,i){setTimeout(function(){$('input').datepicker("show");},1)},
    onSelect: function() { return false }
  });

});
```

```css
td.highlightFull {
  border: none !important;
  padding: 1px 0 1px 1px !important;
  background: none !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}

td.highlightFull a {
  background: #ad3f29 url(bg.png) 50% 50% repeat-x !important;
  border: 1px #88a276 solid !important;
}

td.highlightSemi {
  border: none !important;
  padding: 1px 0 1px 1px !important;
  background: none !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}

td.highlightSemi a {
  background: #ffff33 url(bg.png) 50% 50% repeat-x !important;
  border: 1px #88a276 solid !important;
}

#datepicker tbody [data-event=click] { pointer-events: none; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="datepicker"></div>
```